# NodeJS executable in PATH but not recognized for Java Appium code

Tags: javascript, appium, appium-android, appium-java

**Question:**

I have installed Node.js, and I've confirmed that it's in the PATH, as evidenced by the output of the `which node` command:

```bash
/Users/satyam.shishodiya/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/node
```

However, when I run my Java code for Appium automation, which includes starting the Appium server, I encounter the following error:

```
NodeJS is either not installed or its executable not present in PATH
```

Here's my Java code:

```java
package myAster;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.options.UiAutomator2Options;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder;

public class AppTest {
    
    @Test
    public void appiumBasics() throws MalformedURLException {
        //code to start service
        // AndroidDriver, IOS Driver
        // appium code -> appium server -> emulator device
        
        AppiumDriverLocalService service = new AppiumServiceBuilder()
                .withAppiumJS(new File("//Users//satyam.shishodiya//.nvm//versions//node//v18.17.1//lib//node_modules//appium//build//lib//main.js"))
                .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1").usingPort(4723).build();
        service.start();
        
        UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();
        options.setDeviceName("Pixel7Pro");
        options.setApp("//Users//satyam.shishodiya//Documents//eclipse-workspace//appium//src//test//java//resources//myAster.apk");
        
        AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), options);
        
        //actual automation
        
        driver.quit();
        service.stop();
        //stop server
    }
}
```

To set the PATH, I added the following line to my .profile file:

```bash
eval 'export PATH=$PATH:/Users/satyam.shishodiya/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin/node'
```

Before making this change, I could still verify the executable path using the `which node` command. What might be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?